# PHP and preg_match Regex to pull number with decimal out of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, decimal

Pretty basic stuff here, trying to pull the number **14.5** out of this string using regex and php but I can't seem to get syntax correct.  Also, the number is dynamic and may not always be a decimal but the goal here is to try and pull a number between the word `Weight:` and `</li>`:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Manufacturer: something</li>
    <li>Model: 1216D101</li>
    <li>Condition: New</li>
    <li>Dimensions: 12" x 16"</li>
    <li>Sold by the Dozen</li>
    <li>Weight: 14.5 Lbs.</li>
  </ul>
```

This is what I have so far and have tried variations but keep falling short:

```
if (preg_match("/\Weight:\(\d+)\.(\d*?)\<\/li>/", $desc, $WEIGHT) == true)
    {  echo $WEIGHT[0];  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/Weight: ((?:\d+)(?:\.\d*)?)/
```

The matched number will be available in `$WEIGHT[1]`.

If you don't want to capture the `.` in numbers like `123.`:

```
/Weight: ((?:\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

Comment: This would match things that it shouldn't (e.g. `123.`), and not match things that it should (e.g. `123`).

Comment: Interesting.  This seems to do the trick, however drrcknlsn may be on to something.  I'm unsure if I will run into that problem without further testing, so far it works though.

Comment: `123.` is a valid number. This regex matches `123`.

Comment: @HansEngel: Fair enough, with respect to `123.`, but your original regex that you've since changed quite a few times would not match `123`, as it was `(\d+)\.(\d*)` or some such, making the `.` required for the match.  It looks like you have since fixed it though.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/Weight: (\d+(\.\d+)?)/', $desc, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('<li>Weight: (\d+)\.?(\d+)?.+</li>', // ...
```

Should to the trick

Comment: This requires the number to have a decimal and decimal points.  The OP said the number "may not always be a decimal."

Answer (score 0):

if you JUST want to match a number integer OR decimal

```
 if (preg_match('/^(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/',$num)) echo "$num is integer or decimal";
```